# Ubuntu Core "Cannot open display:"

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

so I got Ubuntu Core up and running on a Raspi 3. Now I tried out a few snaps, but when it comes to snaps with a GUI I face a problem (I am connected via ssh). So I run `gimp`  and it gives me the output: `Cannot open display:`

That's it. I know that there are often issues with the display output when connected via ssh, but I could not solve it with the `export DISPLAY` command. Does anyone have a clue? I would like to see gimp open and running on a screen connected via HDMI to the raspi.

I do not want to use SSH forwarding, because for my problem I won't have another device connected to the raspi during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu core doesn't ship a graphical stack like X11 or wayland and is not designed to support most graphical snaps today. There are people working on standalone X11 snap that you can install and operate but again, this is not something that is supported yet. Such devices are typically used for headless operation or for kiosks with a special, locked down application that does display on the connected screen.